# Can't make a searchbar, either via w3schools or ajax live search work on my site

Tags: php, html, ajax, xml, searchbar

I'm trying to make a search function for my website.
I got this code from w3schools but it doesn't work:

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
<div id="livesearch"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
          "' target='_blank'>" . 
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
  <link>
    <title>HTML a tag</title>
    <url>https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp</url>
  </link>
  <link>
    <title>HTML br tag</title>
    <url>https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp</url>
  </link>
  <link>
    <title>CSS background Property</title>
    <url>https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp</url>
  </link>
  <link>
    <title>CSS border Property</title>
    <url>https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp</url>
  </link>
  <link>
    <title>JavaScript Date Object</title>
    <url>https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp</url>
  </link>
  <link>
    <title>JavaScript Array Object</title>
    <url>https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp</url>
  </link>
</pages>
```

But when I try to implement this I get the following error:
[image]

I also tried other searching methods, like Ajax live search but I can't seem to set it up correctly.

It would be great if someone could either fix this code or help me set up Ajax live search.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That doesn't really look like an error, it just looks like PHP code. Check out this post to help figure out why that could be happening. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: I can't figure out what I am doing wrong from that page

Comment: Okay, first of all, are you accessing the page from a web server that has php installed?

Comment: I am trying my code from the brackets program.